# can a nida apply eyedrops to her husband?

Tags: halacha, niddah

A nidah is not allowed to touch her husband directly. how about something like dropping eye drops into her husband's eyes (ex. not sick. just for mild dry eyes, no one else can do it). Is this included in the prohibition?

Comment: CYLOR for practical advice.

Comment: Beer Moshe is also Matir

Answer (score 6):

Rav Elyashiv (קובץ תשובות חלק ג' סע' קל"ח) paskens that it is permitted.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In sefer Mareh Cohen(Rav Yitzchak Rubin) he says its permmited. If she needs to open eye then she should use a davar chotzetz (cloth).

Comment: even if he is not sick?